# Range Format with `cleveref`

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to customise the way multiple references are handled in the `cleveref` package. I would like to have the form `(eq0, eq1, eq3, eq4)`, ie comma separated, *unless* the set of references form a complete range, in which case I would like an en-dash, eg `(eq0--eq3)` instead of `(eq0, eq1, eq2, eq3)`.

However, I do not use the `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` environment. I use the following macro: `\newcommand{\nt}{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}` and `\begin{equation*} ... \nt \end{equation*}`. If it were only equations, I could just swap to using the non-`*`-d version. However, there are other reasons why I wish to persist with that `\nt` macro.

Below is a minimal working example. (Apologies that it is quite long, but it is as short as I could get!)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}

\newcommand{\nt}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

\crefformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{(#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3)}{, #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5#2#6)}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{-1}

\begin{equation}\label{0} 0\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{1} 1\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{2} 2\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{3} 3\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{4} 4\end{equation}
\begin{equation*}\nt\label{5} 5\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\nt\label{6} 6\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\nt\label{7} 7\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\nt\label{8} 8\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\nt\label{9} 9\end{equation*}

\texttt{\textbackslash cref\{0,1,3,4\}}: \cref{0,1,3,4}
%this prints the desired `(0, 1, 3, 4)`

\texttt{\textbackslash cref\{5,6,8,9\}}: \cref{5,6,8,9}
%this prints the undesired `(5--9)`

\end{document}
```

It seems that `cleveref` somehow does not know that this is not a full range when I use the `\nt` macro. Maybe it's something to do with `cleveref` looking at the *environment*, rather than the *counter*?

---

**Edit.**
Mico appeared to suggest using `\refstepcounter` and placing `\nt` before `\label`. They did not give further details, but I made the changes above anyway.

Comment: Why do you use `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` instead of `\refstepcounter{equation}`? And why do you place `\label` before `\nt`?

Comment: (1) Good point. This is something I got off TeX.SE years ago and never changed. (2) Does it make a difference? It doesn't change the output of the MWE above permuting these two

Comment: Is this a more difficult question than I was perhaps anticipating? Is it perhaps worth my contacting the package author directly?